# Unable to locate package libboost-python1-40-dev?

Tags: python, package

I'm installing sorl-thumbnail and one of its requirements is libboost-python1.40-dev.

When I try to install it with `sudo apt-get install libboost-python1.40-dev`, I'm getting `E:Unable to locate package libboost-python1.40-dev`. How can I install this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a wrong version?
This works for me:

```
 sudo apt-get install libboost-python1.49-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a different version of the package.
What does

```
apt-cache search boost-python
```

give you? That's the name of the package you need to install (use the `dev` variant if you get multiple results).

If your package version is lower than 1.40, you can do two things:

- cross your fingers and hope things will work
- upgrade your system, or find a way to add the updated package to your package manager

If your package version is larger than 1.40, you should be reasonably safe, unless there was some awkward backwards-incompatible change.